# saveRow not working if cell content is blank

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid that uses inline edit. I've made a logic to saveRow when clicking out of the grid and also the standard on enter press. It works great unless the user doesn't type anything into the cell. This is what happens:  [image]

As you can see, the input is still there and it'll only desappear if I fill the cell with some text. How can I avoid this behavior?

Here is my code:

```
$('body').bind('click', function(e) { // Click listener
    if (lastSelectedRow != "" ) { //if a row is selected for edit 
        if($(e.target).closest('#grid_data').length == 0) { 
            $('#grid_data').saveRow(lastSelectedRow, false, 'clientArray');
            lastSelectedRow="";
        } 
    } 
});

$("#grid_data").jqGrid({    
    url: '../json/jsonData.jsp',
    datatype: 'json',
    jsonReader:{
        root: 'rows', //dados
        page: 'page', //página requisitada
        total: 'total', //total de páginas
        records: 'records' //total de registros
    },      
    pager: '#pager_data',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    autoencode: true, 
    height: 230,
    width: 650,
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "Campos de Metadados",
    cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    colNames:['ID','ID Metadata','Descrição','Valor'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'metadataFieldId', width:80, sorttype:"int", sortable: true, editable: false},
        {name:'metadataId', hidden: true},
        {name:'description', width:235, sortable: true, editable: false},
        {name:'value', width:235, sortable: true, editable: true, editrules:{required:true}}
    ],
    afterEditCell: function(rowId, cellName, value, iRow, iCol) {
        // Change text color
        var $row = $('#'+iRow+'_value');
        $row.css('color','black');
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (id && id !== lastSelectedRow) {
            if (lastSelectedRow != undefined) {
                $('#grid_data').saveRow(lastSelectedRow, false, 'clientArray');
            }
            $this.jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
            lastSelectedRow = id;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the reason is in usage [editrules: {required: true}](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules) which don't allow the usage of empty value in the column `'value'`. You should just remove the value if you want to allow to save empty value in the column.